# when to say that an algorithm is a learning algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, algorithms, definition

If I have an algorithm that deals with data, and the result of this algorithm is binary classes,
When can i say that this algorithm is a classification algorithm ( machine learning algorithm)??

Comment: you can say it's machine learning whenever you want people to throw bricks of cash at you

Comment: You must ask yourself: who is learning? If you're learning about the phenomenon by running different algorithms, then it's not ML. However, if you run classification, get good results but you didn't learn anything, then it must be machine that learned something. So, in this case it's ML

Comment: it can be data filtering but not classification @Aksakal

Answer (score 3):

Everything that computer does "deals" with some kind of data. We are talking about [machine learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning), when the algorithm can adapt, and change its behavior, based on the data, where the reactions are not based on pre-defined set of rules (traditional programming), but the program can by itself find the optimal solution, given some definition of optimality.

There is a number of formal definitions, for example [Godfellow et al (2016)](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/ml.html), quote Mitchell:

> A machine learning algorithm is an algorithm that is able to learn
>   from data. But what do we mean by learning? Mitchell (1997) provides a
>   succinct deﬁnition: “A computer program is said to learn from
>   experience $E$ with respect to some class of tasks $T$ and performance
>   measure $P$, if its performance at tasks in $T$, as measured by $P$,
>   improves with experience $E$.” One can imagine a wide variety of
>   experiences $E$, tasks $T$, and performance measures $P$, and we do
>   not attempt in this book to formally deﬁne what may be used for each
>   of these entities. [...]

But some argue that this definition is more about [reinforcement learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinforcement_learning), then machine learning in general. It is hard to come with formal and precise definition given the wide variety, and the number of possible use cases for machine learning.